# Why does the tableau package raise the error "undefined control sequence" for \newpsstyle?

Tags: errors, diagrams, logic

I'm running ubuntu 11.04, and trying tableau to draw logic diagrams for the first time.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tableau}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\
Here I use $\Box$ to represent necessity and $\Diamond$ to represent
possibility.

a) Whether $\Diamond(P\parallel Q) \vdash\Diamond P\parallel\Dimaond Q$

\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
...
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/tableaux/tableau.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.151 \newpsstyle
                 {TabDblBarre}{linewidth=.4pt,doubleline=true,doublesep=.6pt}
?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your questions by adding 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, as I did.

Comment: The [package description](http://ctan.org/pkg/tableaux) mentions is "uses PStricks". Follow @Herbert's suggestion *before* `\usepackage{tableau}`.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like `tableau` is a rather ugly package which does not require its dependencies. For that reason, you need to include the `pstricks` package yourself.

Note also that you mispelled `\Diamond`. The following works:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tableau}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

    Here I use $\Box$ to represent necessity and $\Diamond$ to represent
possibility.

a) Whether $\Diamond(P\parallel Q) \vdash\Diamond P\parallel\Diamond Q$

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

The `variations` package is a *bit* cleaner than `tableau` and has a proper documentation.

You can also achieve a "tableau de variations" (would love to know the name in English) following [Daniel Flippo's method](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/tabvar/index.html), which at least works fine with standard LaTeX engines (such as PDFTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabvar}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tabvar}{|C|CCCCCCCCC|} \hline
x &-\infty & &-\sqrt[3]{2} & &0 & & 1 & &+\infty
\\ \hline
f\u2019(x) & &- & &- &\dbarre &- & 0 &+ &
\\ \hline
\niveau{3}{3}f(x)
&+\infty &\decroit
&0 &\decroit
&\discont{-\infty}{<}{+\infty} &\decroit
&\frac{3}{2} &\croit
&+\infty
\\ \hline
\end{tabvar}\]

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: Using Daniel's method]

A proper package implementing this technique might not hurt anyone.

Comment: Thank you. This resolves it. I'll contact the tableau author to to point to this.

Comment: @Evelyn: if it resolves it, please accept the answer by checking it.

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{pstricks}
```

before package `tableau` is missing